# How to handle exception in cursor when given record is not found in a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am updating `emp3` (same as emp table) using a Cursor For loop,

```
DECLARE 
   CURSOR incr_cur IS SELECT * FROM emp3 FOR UPDATE OF sal;
   v_job emp3.job%TYPE := '&ENTER_Job';
   v_cnt INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR r_l IN incr_cur LOOP
    IF v_job IN (r_l.job) THEN
      UPDATE emp3 SET sal = sal + 100 WHERE CURRENT OF incr_cur;
    END IF;
 END LOOP;

 FOR r_l IN incr_cur LOOP
    IF v_job IN (r_l.job) THEN
      v_cnt := v_cnt + 1;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Salary of ' || r_l.ename || ' is Incremented by 100 and the Updated Salary is: $' || r_l.sal);
    END IF;
 END LOOP;

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Salary of '|| v_cnt ||' Employees are Updated');
END;
```

When executing the PL/SQL block it will ask for the job,
I give `MANAGER`, then the salary of the employees who are `MANAGER` is incremented by 100.
The `emp3` table has 5 JOB categories `CLERK`, `MANAGER`, `ANALYST`, `SALESMAN` and `PRESIDENT`.
Then how to display the Message **The Job is not listed so update is not possible.**, if a user inputs a JOB which is not in the table such as `DEVELOPER`.
I had tried with exception handling but could not get it to work.

Comment: any reason you're not doing this whole thing with a single SQL `update` statement with a `where` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a separate step. Just attempt the update and if no rows were updated, say so. If you want it to be an exception, then raise one with `raise_application_error`.

Assuming this is a learning exercise and this is why you don't want to just do an ordinary `update`, you might do something like this:

```
declare 
    k_job constant emp3.job%type := '&JOB';

    cursor employees_cur is
        select * from emp3
        where  job = k_job
        for update of sal;

    v_update_count integer := 0;
    v_payroll_increase integer := 0;
begin
    for r in employees_cur loop
        update emp3 set sal = sal + 100 where current of employees_cur;
        dbms_output.put_line('Salary for ' || r.ename || ' is incremented by $100 from $' || r.sal || ' to $' || (r.sal +100));
        v_update_count := v_update_count + 1;
        v_payroll_increase := v_payroll_increase + 100;
    end loop;

    if v_update_count = 0 then
        dbms_output.put_line('No staff are currently employed as ' || k_job ||'. Payroll is unchanged.');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('Updated salary of '|| v_update_count ||' employee' || case when v_update_count <> 1 then 's' end||'.');
        dbms_output.put_line('Payroll increased by $'||v_payroll_increase||'.');
    end if;
end;
/

Enter value for job: SALESMAN
Salary for ALLEN is incremented by $100 from $1600 to $1700
Salary for WARD is incremented by $100 from $1250 to $1350
Salary for MARTIN is incremented by $100 from $1250 to $1350
Salary for TURNER is incremented by $100 from $1500 to $1600
Updated salary of 4 employees.
Payroll increased by $400.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

For a nonexistent job, you get this:

```
Enter value for job: ASTRONAUT
No staff are currently employed as ASTRONAUT. Payroll is unchanged.
```

(In this example, `v_payroll_increase` is always 100 times `v_update_count`, but if you wanted to give a 10% raise or differing increases by department etc it might be more useful.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option: check whether such a job exists; if not, query will return `NO_DATA_FOUND` which you can handle and raise an exception with appropriate message. Otherwise, proceed with the `UPDATE`.

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_job emp.job%type;
  3  begin
  4    begin
  5      select job
  6        into l_job
  7        from emp
  8        where job = '&ENTER_Job'
  9          and rownum = 1;
 10    exception
 11      when no_data_found then
 12        raise_application_error(-20000, 'That job does not exist');
 13    end;
 14
 15    -- Job exists, so - go on with the update
 16  end;
 17  /
Enter value for enter_job: MANAGER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
Enter value for enter_job: DEVELOPER
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: That job does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 12


SQL>
```

P.S. Forgot to mention: I prefer doing such a job through a stored procedure (which accepts job name as a parameter) instead of an anonymous PL/SQL block.